# T-60 suddenly crashing. What is average heat readings?

Tags: laptop, fan

My IBM t-60 is suddenly crashing. When I run speedfan I see that all laptop heat source are too hot. What is the average temperature that it should run at?

EDIT based on response by ntw1103: Speedfan shows me 3 readings that average in the mid-fifties C. Perhaps this is not the problem?

Comment: Do you have an Intel, or ATI graphics card? I have experienced T-60s with the ATI graphics card overheating and crashing.Eventually, the chip melted... I'm not sure how to take a temperature reading off the GPU. realtemp, hwmonitor, SpeedFan, and GPU-Z didn't work. I wouldn't think that is the problem, but it might be something to consider if the computer feels hot.

Comment: It doesn't feel all that hot. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using http://www.techpowerup.com/realtemp/
on 3 t60 laptops I have here I got an average of `63°C`

readouts:

75°  - heavy usage, it was playing flash videos for over an hour.

72°  - moderate usage running for over an hour.

43°  - Light usage, running for about 10 minutes.